# asp:NextPreviousPagerField : setting NextPageText in code behind

Tags: asp.net, .net, datapager

I have a datapager on the page as follows :

```
            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvSearchResults">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="False" ShowNextPageButton="False" ButtonType="Link" ButtonCssClass="last_button" />
                    <asp:NumericPagerField NumericButtonCssClass="numeric_button" CurrentPageLabelCssClass="current_page" NextPreviousButtonCssClass="next_button" />
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowLastPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" ButtonType="Link" ButtonCssClass="last_button" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
```

I want to set the NextPageText Property of the asp:NextPreviousPagerField from code behind. (I have to read it programatically from a dictionary)

Can someone tell me reach this property in code-behind ?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution. We can reach the property from code behind so :

```
((NextPreviousPagerField)this.DataPager.Fields[0]).PreviousPageText = "";
```